# Let $V$ be a non-zero vector space over a field $F$. Let $S \subseteq V$ be a non-empty set.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a non-zero vector space over a field $F$. Let $S \subseteq V$ be a non-empty set. Consider the
following properties of $S$:

(I) For any vector space $W$ over $F$, any map $f : S \to W$ extends to a linear map from $V$ to
$W$.

(II) For any vector space $W$ over $F$ and any two linear maps $f; g : V \to W$ satisfying $f(s) =
g(s)$ for all $s \in S$, we have $f(v) = g(v)$ for all $v \in V$ .

(III) S is linearly independent.

(IV) The span of S is V:

Which of the following statement(s) is /are true?

(A) (I) $\implies$ (IV)

(B) (I) $\implies$ (III)

(C) (II) $\implies$ (III)

(D) (II) $\implies$ (IV)

My attempt

If $S$ is linearly independent. $S$ will form a basis for span($S$). We can extend any subspace basis to vector space basis. We can define function values at extended points in the basis. So,(III) $\implies$ (I). similar argument, we can deduce $(III)\implies (II)$. But answer given was (B) and (D) options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as far as I can tell, III $\implies I$ is correct. However, III $\implies$ II is not. This look at $V=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S=(1,0)$. $S$ is clearly linearly independent. Now, let $T:V\to \mathbb{R}$ where $T(x,y) = y$ and $S:V\to\mathbb{R}$ where $S(x,y)=0$.
$T(1,0)=S(1,0) = 0$, but these aren't the same map. This is because just because the map can be extended, it cannot be extended uniquely unless $S$ contains a full basis. Notice that none of these are options, however.

Now, let's look at the answers choices.

A) I $\implies$ IV. This is false, as any linearly independent subset satisfies property 1, but not all of them fulfill property IV.

B) I $\implies III$. This is true. Suppose S has property I but not property III. $S$ must have at least two elements or contains the zero vector. In the latter case, you can't extend any function $f:S\to W$ that doesn't take 0 to 0. So suppose S has more than one element. We have that for each $v\in S$ there exists $\lambda_v\in F$ such that $\sum_{v\in S} \lambda_v v = 0$ and with at least one $\lambda_v\neq 0$. Call this one $v_0$. We have that $v_0 = \frac{1}{\lambda_{v_0}}\sum_{v\in (S-v_0)}\lambda_v v$. Now let's construct an $f:S\to W$ which can't be extended. This will be a contradiction. First, for any $v\in S$ where $v\neq v_0$ $f(v)$ can be any element of $W$. For $f(v_0)$ pick any element of $W$ other than $\frac{1}{\lambda_{v_0}}\sum_{v\in (S-v_0)}\lambda_v f(v)$ (we are assuming $W$ has more than 1 element, but we get to pick $W$ so that is fine. $f$ can't be linearly extended because then $f(v_0) = f(\frac{1}{\lambda_{v_0}}\sum_{v\in (S-v_0)}\lambda_v v) = 
\frac{1}{\lambda_{v_0}}\sum_{v\in (S-v_0)}\lambda_v f(v) \neq f(v_0)$. We have a contradiction as we are assuming property I.

C) II $\implies$ III. For an easy counter-example, just pick $S=\{0\}$. Every linear map agrees on $S$, but $S$ is not linearly independent.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$

D) II $\implies$ IV. Suppose $\span S \neq V$. Let $f:V\to W$ be any linear map. Now, define $g:V\to W$ as follows. First, for $v\in\span S$ g(v)=f(v). Now, define a basis on the the part of $V$ which lies outside of $\span S$. For any of these, $g(v)$ is maps to any value except $f(v)$. This shows that II doesn't hold as $g$ can be extended to a linear function and we defined $g$ such that $g$ and $f$ agree on $\span S$. In other words, a subset of $V$ only determines the whole of a linear transformation on $V$ only if it's span is all of $V$. By contraposition, this is equivalent to II $\implies$ IV.